# If $X,Y$ standard normal, find conditional distribution of $X+Y$ given $X>0$ and $Y>0$

Tags: probability-distributions

The (old qualifying exam) question is this: if $X,Y$ are independent standard normals, what is the distribution of $Z=X+Y$ *given* that $X>0,Y>0$?

We must find $P(Z\le z, X>0,Y>0)$ (and then divide this by $P(X>0,Y>0)=\frac14$), which means integrating $\frac1{2\pi}e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}$ over the triangle $x+y\le z$ in the first quadrant. I figured using polar coordinates was the right idea. Converting $x+y=z$ to polar, we get $r(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)=r\sqrt{2}\cos(\theta-\pi/4)=z$, so
\begin{align*}
P(Z\le z,X>0,Y>0)
&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\frac{z\sec(\theta-\frac\pi4)}{\sqrt2}}e^{-r^2/2}\cdot r\,dr\,d\theta\\
&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}(-e^{-r^2/2})\bigg|^{\frac{z\sec(\theta-\frac\pi4)}{\sqrt2}}_0\,d\theta\\
&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}1-\exp\left(-\frac{z^2\sec^2(\theta-\pi/4)}{4}\right)\,d\theta\\
&=\frac14-\frac{e^{-z^2/4}}{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\exp\left(-\frac{\tan^2(\theta-\pi/4)}{4}\right)\,d\theta
\end{align*}
However, neither I nor Mathematica know what to do with the last integral. Am I missing any clever tricks, or is the best we can do to write $P(Z\le z|X>0,Y>0)=1-\frac{2}\pi\cdot e^{-z^2/4}\cdot\tau$, with $\tau$ being the value of the horrible integral?

Comment: If it's really true that $P(Z\le z|X>0,Y>0)=1-\frac{2}\pi\cdot e^{-z^2/4}\cdot\tau$ (apologies, I haven't checked your work), then set $z=0$. Then $0 = 1 - {2\over\pi}\tau$, and you've got the value of $\tau$.

Comment: Your comment has made me realize my work was wrong.

Comment: For $z>0$, isn't $P(Z\le z,X>0,Y>0)=\int_0^\infty P(0<X\le z-y)\phi(y)\,dy=\int_0^\infty \Phi(z-y)\phi(y)\,dy-1/4$ ? Then to find the density one would have to find $\int_0^\infty \phi(z-y)\phi(y)\,dy$, which could be possibly done.

Comment: Could you tell me what the final answer should turn out to be for the density of $Z\mid X>0,Y>0$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of the circular symmetry of the joint density of two independent standard normal random variables,

- $P\{(X,Y) \in \text{triangle with vertices at $(0,0), (z,0), (0,z)$}\}$ is 
  *one-fourth* the probability that the random point lies in the *square* 
  with vertices $(z,0), (0,z), (-z,0), (0,-z)$.
- Rotating the square about the origin till the sides are parallel to the axes
  does not change $P\{(X,Y) \in \text{rotated square}\}$
- $P\{(X,Y) \in \text{rotated square}\}$, whose vertices are at 
  $\left(\pm \frac{z}{\sqrt{2}}, \pm \frac{z}{\sqrt{2}}, \right)$, is left
  to you as an exercise.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes I can, very nice answer!

Comment: Apologies for reviving this old post but I was looking for a solution to this very problem and found this. So, if I am not wrong (correct me please!) the conditional distribution turns out to be $P(X\in[-z/\sqrt{2},z/\sqrt{2}],Y\in[-z/\sqrt{2},z/\sqrt{2}])=(2\Phi\big(\dfrac{z}{\sqrt{2}})-1)^2$ from which the conditional density is $f(z)=2(2\Phi(\dfrac{z}{\sqrt{2}}-1)\sqrt{2}\phi(\dfrac{z}{\sqrt{2}})$. Now, if I want to take $E[X+Y|X>0,Y>0]$ then this form will not really help me, will it? Can $\int_0^\infty zf(z)dz$ be evaluated from this? Thanks!!

Comment: @yedaynara Don't ask a different question in a comment; write up a separate question.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate please look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242305/clever-way-of-finding-int-0-infty-x-phix-phixdx Here is the part I am stuck at, while finding the expectation.