# Clever way of finding $\int_0^\infty x\Phi(x)\phi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> Suppose that $\Phi$ and $\phi$ are the Standard Normal c.d.f and p.d.f. respectively. Then, evaluate $$\int_0^\infty x\Phi(x)\phi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

There is no use of my trying to show my approach because none of the techniques I used could initiate the solving process. I have, however, obtained the value of $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\Phi(x)\phi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$Any help is appreciated.

The way I proceeded:

1. Orthogonalization of the unit square in which the points $(X,Y)$ are situated. This did not work.
2. Supposing that the centroid of the triangle with vertices at $(0,0),(0,z),(z,0)$ will be the answer due to the symmetry between $X$ and $Y$.
3. Integration by parts repeatedly taking $\Phi$ as the second function, which yielded nothing practically.
4. Using the conditional m.g.f.

The question arose in an attempt to find $\mathbb{E}(X+Y|X>0,Y>0)$ where one term contained this integral. The question came in a semester exam. I will not add "self-study" to this because the question precisely stated that this is an immensely important problem in Monte Carlo Methods, something which I have not read.

Comment: You could show how you arrived at the integral you did obtain. Then we could see why you might have had trouble with the other integral.

Comment: Well I did not think that finding this integral was in any way similar to the problem. So, I did not post it.
Okay, if you insist, let me post the solution to this integral.

Comment: By the way, why has this been voted as off-topic?

Comment: robjohn, Actually while I was uploading the solution to find this new integral, I realized there has been a major error. So the integral that I wrote is incorrect. I want to delete that part. But then, will it not seem as if no research effort has been shown, while I had spent literally one whole day trying in vain everything I knew?

Comment: I am not insisting anything. However, it seems that some people want to see [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959) with all questions.

Comment: I'll in that case keep the question unchanged. Thank you for your efforts though.

Comment: If you don't add something, the question will most likely be removed in a while. You still get your answer, but the site suffers from the loss of content. This sounds like our problem and not yours, but since you've benefited from this question, it would be nice to give some [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960).

Comment: I don't understand, what more content can I possibly add? I have stated that my approach was wrong. The answer as you can see should be $\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}$ and not what I wrote. I would not want this question to get deleted but I also feel that people should carefully read all the comments before voting a question to be closed. This is a ridiculous point. Even more so because I clearly mentioned I tried integration by parts but failed. Do they want me to post my 5 page long attempt, which included transformations, by parts, scaling, orthogonality, expectation, etc.?

Comment: Anyway, I am adding as much context as I can.

Comment: And you've gotten one reopen vote already. I would vote to reopen myself, but since I am a moderator, my vote would immediately reopen the question. It is best to let the community decide.

Comment: I don't sincerely want your answer to be lost if this question is closed, so that one reopen vote which you see comes from me only. :P If it is unethical, I will remove my vote. But now I feel the question context has been clarified. Thanks for taking the pain robjohn. Much appreciated.

Comment: No, it is not unethical. Give it a while. Others will probably vote to reopen. Other possibilities for context: Where did you encounter the question? Was it for a class? Was it from a book? What topic were you studying when you encountered the problem?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but isn't $E(X+Y\mid X>0,Y>0)=E(X\mid X>0)+E(Y\mid Y>0)=2E(X\mid X>0)$ ?

Comment: Could you tell me what value should one get of $E(X+Y\mid X>0,Y>0)$ and what should be the density of $X+Y\mid X>0,Y>0$ if you have any reference for the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that
$$
-xe^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}e^{-x^2/2}
$$
Since $\Phi(0)=\frac12$, we can integrate by parts to get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty x\Phi(x)\phi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty x\Phi(x)e^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty \Phi(x)\,\mathrm{d}e^{-x^2/2}\\
&=\frac1{2\sqrt{2\pi}}+\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1{2\sqrt{2\pi}}+\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1{2\sqrt{2\pi}}+\frac1{2\pi}\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\\
&=\frac{1+\sqrt2}{4\sqrt\pi}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Using the same procedure as above, $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\Phi(x)\phi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac1{2\sqrt\pi}$$

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried *integration by parts* together with the knowledge that the *antiderivative* of $x\phi(x)$ is $-\phi(x)$? The answer is readily computable via this approach.