# Expectation involving multiple RV's

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, expected-value, conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution

$X$ follows $N(0,1).$ I am supposed to find $E[X\phi(X)]$, where $\phi(X)$ is the CDF of X

I know that
$X$~ $N(0,1)$ and $Y = \phi(X)$~$U[0,1]$ , but I am not able to find the distribution of $XY$ because they are not independent.

How do I solve this?

Comment: You are over complicating it by defining $Y$. It is a function of $X$ so define $g: X \mapsto X\phi(X)$ and use [Lotus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician).

Comment: @NikolajPedersen, can you elaborate this method? I still don't understand.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242305/clever-way-of-finding-int-0-infty-x-phix-phix-mathrmdx

Comment: [Showing $2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x) F(x) \ dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ for standard normal pdf and cfd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2855794/showing-2-int-infty-infty-x-fx-fx-dx-frac1-sqrt-pi-for-s)

Answer (score 2):

The CDF of X is $\Phi(x)$; $\phi(x)$ is its density. This is important because when you calculate the requested mean with L.O.T.U.S. you have

$$\mathbb{E}[X\Phi_X(x)]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\Phi(x)\phi(x)dx$$

and you can solve it by parts

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X\Phi_X(x)] 
& =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\underbrace{\Phi(x)}_{f}\cdot \underbrace{x\phi(x)}_{g'}dx\\
&=0+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-x^2/2}e^{-x^2/2}dx\\
& =\frac{1}{2\pi}\sqrt{\pi}\\
& =\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for hint, but I am not able to understand the partitions of the integral. It would be useful if you could elaborate further.

Comment: @SohamGhosh : answer edited...you can accept my answer in order to encourage me to give further details

Comment: thanks! Understood