# Expected value of the maximum of $3$ normal variables

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, order-statistics

I want to prove that for $3$ variables $X_1,X_2,X_3$ from normal distribution with $\mu =0,\sigma =1$ for each, $\mathbb{E}(\max \{X_1,X_2,X_3\})\approx 0.85$.
I found the following formula: $\mu +\frac{3}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\sigma$, which shows this, but I do not know how to prove it. (It would be sufficient to prove it only for $\mu =0,\sigma =1$).
In addition I need to prove for a general $k\in \mathbb{N}$ that $\mathbb{E}(\max \{X_1,X_2,\ldots ,X_k\})<\mathbb{E}(\max \{X_1,X_2,\ldots ,X_{k+1}\})$.
How can this be shown? Thank you!

Comment: Think about figuring out the cdf for the maximum and then after knowing that you can determine the pdf and then the mean of the maximum.

Comment: For your second question, note that (i) $\max\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_k\}\le\max\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{k+1}\}$ and (ii) the probability that $\max\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_k\}$ is strictly less than $\max\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{k+1}\}$ is the probability that $X_{k+1}$ is the largest of the $X_i$, which is exactly $\frac{1}{k+1}$. This probability is non-zero, so the expectation must be greater by a non-zero amount.

Answer (score 2):

For the calculation, the [extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Tippett%E2%80%93Gnedenko_theorem) might be helpful, in particular the [Gumbel distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution).

For the proof, start by determining the distribution of the maximum of two normal random variables, then generalize the idea for larger $k$. For $k = 2$,

$$P(\max\{X_1, X_2\} \leq x) = P(X_1 \leq x \wedge X_2 \leq x),$$
which by independence is equal to
$$P(X_1 \leq x) P(X_2 \leq x) = \Phi(x)^2,$$

where $\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF. Then you can calculate the expectation via the Layer-Cake representation
$$E[Y] = -\int_{-\infty}^0 F_Y(x) dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} (1 - F_Y(x)) dx, $$
where for a random variable $Y$, $F_Y$ is its CDF. The trick is noticing that the integrand of the positive part gets bigger and integrand of the negative part gets smaller as $k$ increases...

Answer (score 2):

Denote $\max(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ by $X$.  Assuming independence, it is easy to derive the distribution function of $X$ is $F(x) = \Phi(x)^3$, hence the density function of $X$ is $f(x) = F'(x) = 3\Phi^2(x)\phi(x)$, where $\Phi(x)$ and $\phi(x)$ are distribution function and density function of standard normal distribution.  It thus follows that
$$E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x) dx = 3\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\Phi^2(x)\phi(x)dx 
= 3\int_{-\infty}^0x\phi(x)\Phi^2(x)dx + 3\int_0^\infty x\phi(x)\Phi^2(x)dx. $$

For the first integral, let $t = -x$ and use $\Phi(-t) = 1 - \Phi(t), \phi(-t) = \phi(t)$, it follows that
\begin{align*}
 & \int_{-\infty}^0x\phi(x)\Phi^2(x)dx \\
=& -\int_0^\infty t\phi(t)(1 - \Phi(t))^2dt = -\int_0^\infty t\phi(t)(1 - 2\Phi(t) + \Phi^2(t))dt \\
=& -\int_0^\infty t\phi(t)dt + 2\int_0^\infty t\phi(t)\Phi(t)dt - \int_0^\infty t\phi(t)\Phi^2(t)dt.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
E(X) = -3\int_0^\infty t\phi(t)dt + 6\int_0^\infty t\phi(t)\Phi(t)dt,
\end{align*}
where (for the derivation of the second integral, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242305/clever-way-of-finding-int-0-infty-x-phix-phix-mathrmdx?rq=1))
\begin{align*}
& \int_0^\infty t\phi(t) dt = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty te^{-t^2/2}dt = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{-y}dy = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}, \\
& \int_0^\infty t\phi(t)\Phi(t) dt = \frac{1+\sqrt2}{4\sqrt\pi}.
\end{align*}
i.e.,
\begin{align}
E(X) = \frac{3}{2\sqrt{\pi}}.
\end{align}

---

Assume $X_1, \ldots, X_{k + 1}$ i.i.d $\sim N(0, 1)$, let $Z_i = \max(X_1, \ldots, X_i), i = k, k + 1$.  To prove this inequality, it is easier to apply the expectation formula mentioned in @gandalfbalrogslayer's answer.  It follows that
\begin{align*}
 E(Z_i) = -\int_{-\infty}^0\Phi^i(t)dt + \int_0^\infty(1 - \Phi^i(t)) dt 
= \int_0^\infty[1 - \Phi^i(t) - (1 - \Phi(t))^i]dt, 
\end{align*}
whence
\begin{align*}
E(Z_{k + 1}) - E(Z_k) = \int_0^\infty[(\Phi^k(t) - \Phi^{k + 1}(t)) + 
((1 - \Phi(t))^k - (1 - \Phi(t))^{k + 1})] dt > 0,
\end{align*}
because for every $t > 0$, $\Phi^k(t) - \Phi^{k + 1}(t) > 0$ and $(1 - \Phi(t))^k - (1 - \Phi(t))^{k + 1} > 0$ and the integrand is continuous everywhere on $(0, +\infty)$.

Alternatively, if you are comfortable with measure-theoretic probability, then we can argue as @TonyK suggested in the comment.  As $Z_{k + 1} - Z_k$ is non-negative, and
\begin{align}
& P(Z_{k + 1} - Z_k > 0) = P(X_{k + 1} > Z_k) \\
=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(Z_k < x)\phi(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi^k(x)\phi(x)dx = \frac{1}{k + 1} > 0,
\end{align}
it follows that (e.g., by Theorem $15.2$ (ii) in *Probability and Measure* by Billingsley)
\begin{align*}
E(Z_{k + 1}) - E(Z_k) = E(Z_{k + 1} - Z_k) =\int_\Omega (Z_{k + 1} - Z_k) dP > 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: Ahh, for the last part of your answer using TonyK's suggestion, I assumed $X_1, \ldots, X_k$ and $X_1, \ldots X_{k+1}$ were independent samples and this was just an abuse of notation. If we assume that they are the same sample with the latter having one extra random variable, then the result is trivial...

Comment: @gandalfbalrogslayer Even they are the same sample, it is not entirely trivial -- the non-trivial part is to prove the **strict** "greater than".

Comment: I suppose, but we can use the general fact that $P(X_{n} = \max\{X_1, \ldots, X_{n} \}) = \dfrac{1}{n}$ for a general i.i.d. sample $X_1, \ldots, X_{n}$ with continuous distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the 3 r.v. are iid ?

You can start by computing the CDF of the max of your 3 r.v. by using the fact that if the max is less than x then all three variables are less than x and afterwards using their independency.